# cannot do <div> in <table>, but is <div> in <caption> in <table> allowed

Tags: html, html-table

We are receiving the warning `Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a child of <table>`. and we understand the warning and what we're doing wrong:

**Bad**

```
<table>
  <div>Shouldn't do this</div>
</table>
```

`<caption>` is an element allowed in `<table>`, and a the div is nested in a `<caption>`, we don't get the warning anymore. Is there anything structurally wrong with this? There is still a div in the table, just nested a layer deeper... or is this okay?

**Is this okay?**

```
<table>
  <caption>
    <div>No more warning with this</div>
  </caption>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will be valid provided `div` is defined as a **table cell**.

Set rule `display: table-cell` for `div`:

```
div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: our <div> is not defined as a table-cell, it is an ordinary `display: block` and we are still not getting the warning message. Is it possible that (a) we are not getting a warning and (b) our html structure is still problematic?

Comment: easy enough to add this style to the div, thank you, just trying to understand what is generally allowed and not allowed for this

Comment: @Canovice, Yes, display: block is the default value for div, but even if you do not receive warnings, it is still considered an invalid html. This is the same as putting div in the span tag. There will be no warnings, but this will be considered incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot insert a `div` directly inside of a table. It is not correct HTML, and will result in unexpected output.

I don't understand, you want to apply div's in the `table`? Why would that be?

> Well `caption` is part of `table` same like other tags (`tr`, `td`,
> `th`) It permitted in an  element, as its first descendant.

read more about [caption here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/caption)

Comment: Just FYI I don't get validateDOMNesting warnings when adding a div inside a `caption` or `td` in react@18.2.0 so not sure if this is entirely true.